# Could not find module 'ACSCL_x64.dll'

Tags: python, acs

I'm working with ASC controller on Windows using the acspy package.

Here is a simple script to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
from acspy import acsc

address='127.0.0.1'

controller = Controller(contype='ethernet', n_axes=4)
controller.connect(address)

acsc.runBuffer(controller.hc, acsc.ACSC_BUFFER_3)
```

Then I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'ACSCL_x64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Please tell me where or how do I provide this missing file?

Comment: Not familiar with the library, but from their Github page https://github.com/petebachant/ACSpy: "*Note that the ACS motion control SPiiPlus User-Mode Driver must be installed and running. Contact ACS to obtain this software.*"